# Do these phrases require hyphens? "mock-cried" vs "mock cried"

Tags: meaning, punctuation, hyphenation, style-manuals

Should the following sentences be hyphenated?

I mock cried into his shoulder.

*vs.*

I mock-cried into his shoulder.

---

He smiled at me with his old man charm.

*vs.*

He smiled at me with his old man-charm.

Comment: I've never seen the verb ***to mock[-]cry*** before, but searching for ***she mock cried*** in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+mock+cried%22) returns exactly ***two*** write instances. One has a hyphen, the other doesn't. I'd suggest you *do* include the hyphen, but obviously it's just a stylistic choice, and no-one will think anything of it whichever way you go.

Comment: 'I cried crocodile tears into his shoulder.'